# Slow MySQL query on 2 million entries table

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm trying the following query :

```
SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (2167635,2167638,2182793,2182800,2195791,2195809,2208830,2208837,2212480,2212486)
```

in a 2 million wp_postmeta table. 
Using explain shows that i'm using the existint post_id index. But it takes 5 seconds
to load (which is pretty much unacceptable).

Any ideas on how to optimize that query?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's strange that it runs so slow.  You could try creating a covering index with those three fields in it.

Comment: Can you post the output of a EXPLAIN on this query?

Comment: 1 SIMPLE wp_postmeta range post_id post_id 8 NULL 138 Using where

Comment: Is the `post_id` column, the primary key of `wp_postmeta` table?

Comment: Your `explain` is unreadable. Edit it into the question and include column names, please.

Comment: Voting to close since you obviously don't care about your question any more.

Comment: So, what is the output of `EXPLAIN your_query_here`?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add an index to `post_id` column for result will come more quickly , the values they will be indexed.

```
    ALTER TABLE `wp_postmeta` ADD INDEX `post_id` (`post_id`)
```